# how to calculate this?

Tags: statistics

I need to calculate some **order** of a set of samples, but I do not know what method I should use. For example, there are many *people*, and I get the number of people every of whom has some *apples* (apple<=>people):`0<=>1, 1<=>4, 2<=>16, 3<=>2`. That is to say, there is 1 people who has no apples, there are 4 people every of whom has 1 apple, there 16 people every of whom has 2 apples, and there are 2 people every of whom has 3 apples. And I want to reflect the **order** of the apple possession is 2: Most people have 2 apples everyone. I would like the **order number** is around `2` here, e.g. `2.3` or `1.9`. How should I calculate this order number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want the [mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_%28statistics%29), the most common value.  Maybe you want the [median](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median), the value that half the people have more than and half have less.  Maybe you want the [mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean), the classical average.  For your example, the first two would be exactly 2, the mean would be $\frac {42}{23} \approx 1.83$ which reflects the fact that more people have less than 2 apples than have more.